# What do you call the bathroom's exhaust fan in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Not sure which one sounds normal. Abluftventilator vs Bad-Ventilator vs Badlüfter. Or perhaps some other words. Last time I just used deepl/dictionary for another word and someone said no one uses that word except for store catalogs.

It's the fan on the wall or ceiling that ventilate the bathroom. To remove condensation after showering for example.

Context is it's broken and I need to ask the Hausmeister to call a repairman to fix it.

Comment: Might be useful to know that the common English term (British English at least) for such a fan is an *extractor fan*.

Comment: @dbmag9 You are correct according to google trends. https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=exhaust%20fan,extractor%20fan

Comment: If you are missing such a specific word describing the context is usually also a good option. 
For example: "Der Lüfter in meinem Bad" also describes the device and does not require you to remember a word you will probably use twice in your entire life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to call it and probably all should be understood by your Hausmeister.

- *(Bad)Lüfter* or *Lüfter im Bad*
- *(Bad)Entlüfter* or *Entlüfter im Bad*
- *Lüftungsanlage* or *Lüftungsanlage im Bad*
- ...

Comment: *Austrian* Badventilator, Kloventilator, Häuslventilator

Answer (score 0):

I would just call it, "der Ventilator im Bad."  But I learned my German in the 1970's;-)  (It was the first language I learned).